# Change filename for user when downloading directly from AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am developing an application where I will be storing files on S3. Due to the fact that filenames can be different I have to rename the files to something generic in the bucket so I know which one to get at a later date.

If I was to allow the user to download through my web app, I could change the filename back before sending it on to the user. However I want the user to directly download the file using a temporary secure token such as below.

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new(
  :access_key_id => 1234,
  :secret_access_key => abcd
)
object = s3.buckets['bucket'].objects['path/to/object']
object.url_for(:get, { :expires => 20.minutes.from_now, :secure => true }).to_s
```

But how do I change the filename the user sees when downloading this file back to their original filename?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the S3 object's **Content-disposition** property to `attachment; filename="nameyouwant"` where nameyouwant is, of course, whatever name you want the downloaded file to have by default. When the user downloads from S3 using a web browser, the browser will use the name in the Content-disposition header instead of the URL.

Comment: Thanks. FYI for anyone else coming across this post. Here is an SO question that shows you how to do it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138336/how-do-i-add-or-modify-the-content-disposition-of-an-existing-object-in-amazon-s

Comment: You can also use only the `filename="nameyouwant"` portion without making it an attachment. This is useful to display PDF documents and then when saving, it will get the custom filename.